# How to typecast void pointer based on condition?

Tags: c, pointers, if-statement, casting, void

To explain more, I have two structures-'first' and 'second' having common variables 'jack' and 'jill'. I want to print jack via a pointer based on if-else condition.
I understand at the time of printing I have to typecast the void pointer. But whether the pointer points to struct a or b is decided on run time. 
It is a basic C code. How to overcome this?

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

typedef struct one
{
    int jack;
    float jill;
}a;
typedef struct two
{
    int jack;
    float jill;
    char something;
    int something1;
}b;
a first;
b second;

void *z;

if(1)
{
    a* z;
    z = &first;
    printf("First one");
}
else
{
    b* z;
    z = &second;
    printf("Second one");
}

printf("%d\n", z->jack);


    return 0;
}
```

**Error**

```
prog.c:36:17: warning: dereferencing 'void *' pointer printf("%d\n", z->jack); prog.c:36:17: error: request for member 'jack' in something not a structure or union
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? `printf("b is %F", x)` wants a float argument for `x` (since `%f` is a float format specifier). Not `void`. You'll get a similar error for the same reason with `printf("Value is %d", *a)`. It's unclear what you want here. Are you wanting to print the value as a float in either case?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do either but if you know the resulting type you can cast a void pointer like this `int intVal = *((int *) a);`

Comment: Sorry was the vague/wrong info lurker & fbo3264.Have updated the Q.

Answer (score 2):

You get a compiler warning since the compiler does not understand `z->jack` since `z` is a `void *` (note that the declarations `a* z` and `b* z` are not valid outside the scope of the `if` and `else` block).

To overcome this you can use a function `printJack` as shown in the following listing:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct one
{
    int jack;
    float jill;
}a;

typedef struct two
{
    int jack;
    float jill;
    char something;
    int something1;
}b;


void printJack(void *pStruct, int type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("jack: %d\n", ((a *)pStruct)->jack);
            break;

        default:
            printf("jack: %d\n", ((b *)pStruct)->jack);
            break;
    }
}


/*
**    main
*/
int main(void)
{
    a first;
    b second;
    void *z;

    first.jack = 5;
    second.jack = 4892;

    printJack(&first, 1);
    printJack(&second, 0);

    z = &first;
    printJack(z, 1);

    return (0);
}
```

I've written code like this often and experienced a lot of trouble with it. Not at the time of implementing, since you are knowing what you are typing at that moment but let's say a few years later if you need to extend your code. You will miss a few places where you cast from `void *` to `a *` or `b *` and you'll spend a lot of time debugging what's going on...

Now I'm writing things like this in the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct header
{
    int jack;
    float jill;
} h;

typedef struct one
{
    struct header header;

    /* what ever you like */
}a;

typedef struct two
{
    struct header header;

    char something;
    int something1;

    /* and even more... */
}b;


void printJack(void *pStruct)
{
    printf("jack: %d\n", ((struct header *)pStruct)->jack);
}


/*
**    main
*/
int main(void)
{
    a first;
    b second;
    void *z;

    first.header.jack = 5;
    second.header.jack = 4892;

    printJack(&first);
    printJack(&second);

    v = &first;
    printJack(v);

    return (0);
}
```

As you've noticed I have declared a new `struct header` which covers the the common parts of `struct one` and `struct two`. Instead of casting the `void *` to either `a *` or `b *` a "common" cast to `struct header *` (or `h *`) is done.

By doing so you can easily extend the "common attribtues" of the structs or you can implement further structs using this header and function `printJack` still will work. Additionally there is no need for attribute `type` anymore making is easier to call `printJack`. You can even change the type of `jack` without needing to change it in various places within your code.

But remember that `struct header` needs to be the first element of the structs you use this mechanism. Otherwise you will end up with a few surprises since you are using memory which does not contain the data of the `struct header`...